# algebraic simplification in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm reading up on prolog simplifcation of algebraic expressions and there are some parts I dont understand.

So these are the basic simplications

```
  x+0, x-0, 0+x, 0-x   --> x.
  x*1, x/1, 1*x        --> x.
  -1*x, x*(-1), x/(-1) --> –x.
  x+(-x)               --> x–x.
```

so given an expression

```
 (x+4)*(2-x)
```

how do I make the derivation

```
  (1+0)*(2-x)+(x+4)*(0-1)
```

?

I dont understand how the derivation came about. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess by derivation you mean the mathematical derivative of the function f(x) =  (x+4)*(2-x). This is a very famous old and not so hard computer algebra problem, solutions have been initially written for example in lisp.

A Prolog version is straight forward. You implement derivation rules such as:

```
d/dx (f + g) = d/dx f + d/dx g  
d/dx (f * g) = d/dx f * g + d/dx g * f
etc..
```

I suggest you give it first a try by yourself bevor you check for example [deriv.p](http://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-samples/blob/master/jekrun/benchmark/tests/deriv.p). A computer algebra based autodiff is here [deriv.p](https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-devel/blob/master/jekmin/headless/jekmin/frequent/leibniz/deriv.p).

Bye

Comment: @j4nbur53 It appears that this link is broken again.

Comment: Fixed the link, its now a GitHub link.